# Incomplete translation of the “Your Stack Overflow profile has been deleted” email

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, localization, international-sites

The translation of the “Your Stack Overflow profile has been deleted” email is incomplete on [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

> Olá,
>
> Este é um último e-mail para avisar que seu perfil no Stack Overflow em Português foi removido com sucesso.
>
> If you need anything else, please visit our contact form and select Other for additional help.
>
> Obrigado,
> A equipe do Stack Exchange

and [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/),

> こんにちは。
>
> スタック・オーバーフロー上のあなたのプロフィールを削除しました。
>
> If you need anything else, please visit our contact form and select Other for additional help.
>
> ありがとうございました。
> Stack Exchange チーム

whereas the line “If you need anything else, please visit our contact form and select Other for additional help.” is translated on [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

> Hola,
>
> Esto es un último correo electrónico para informarte de que tu perfil en Stack Overflow en español ha sido borrado con éxito.
>
> Si necesitas algo más, por favor visita nuestro formulario de contacto y selecciona Otro para obtener ayuda adicional.
>
> Gracias.
> El equipo de Stack Exchange

and [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)

> Здравствуйте,
>
> Этим последним письмом уведомляем вас, что ваш профиль был успешно удалён с сайта Русский язык.
>
> Если у вас остались другие вопросы, пожалуйста, посетите нашу контактную форму и выберите Другое для получения дополнительной помощи.
>
> С уважением,
> Команда Stack Exchange

Answer (score 4):

I checked on the [traducir.win](https://traducir.win), the tool we use to translate strings, and found that there are two almost similar strings that say

> If you need anything else, please visit our contact form and select Other for additional help.

Only one of them was translated. I copied the translation and submitted it for Japanese and Portuguese languages. The translation should become available after the next build.